# Azure Data Factory - Content type JSON but response in XML

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-factory, azure-logic-apps

Apologies if my question is too basic but I'm learning the ropes of Azure, so fairly new ... 
I need help with the following questions,

I've written a WebActivity which makes a GET request with the following two header values,

- Content-Type: application/JSON
- Authorization: Bearer

I'm expecting a response in JSON but unfortunately it's coming in an XML 
 format.  . Please refer to image attached,

**Request**

[image: GET Request]

**Request RAW Format**

```
{
"url": "https://someurl.com/data",
"method": "GET",
"headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer <token>"
}
```

}

**Response Received**
Adding some part of response Received,

```
{
"Response": "<Fleet version=\"1\" snapshotTime=\"2020-06-11T14:46:52Z\" xmlns=\"http://standards.iso.org/iso/15143/-3\"><Links><rel>self</rel><href>https://someurl.com/data</href></Links><Links><rel>first</rel><href>https://someurl.com/data</href></Links><Links><rel>last</rel><href>https://someurl.com/data</href></Links><Equipment><EquipmentHeader><OemName>ENIGMA</OemName><EquipmentId>1021</EquipmentId></EquipmentHeader><Location datetime=\"2020-06-11T12:08:59Z\"><Latitude>52.3292240</Latitude><Longitude>-0.1976080</Longitude></Location><CumulativeOperatingHours datetime=\"2020-06-11T15:02:30Z\"><Hour>5119.03</Hour></CumulativeOperatingHours></Equipment><Equipment><EquipmentHeader><OemName>ENIGMA</OemName><EquipmentId>1025</EquipmentId></EquipmentHeader><Location datetime=\"2020-06-11T13:31:57Z\"><Latitude>52.3170160</Latitude><Longitude>- ...
```

Can someone help me in understanding if I'm doing something wrong here, using **Postman**, it works perfectly fine .. I've also tried Azure Logic Apps and get same XML response

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

The `Content-Type: application/json` means the request body is json type, but the response body doesn't have to be json type. You need to set another property in the header:

```
Accept: application/json
```

Hope it helps~

Comment: Thanks Hury, I also tried your suggestion of adding Accept:application/json still the result is same, I'm still receiving XML response which is odd. Just gone through API specification and it seems they've specified that if you send Content-Type JSON then response will be in JSON otherwise response will be in XML